# Use string in text file as a variable in batch

Tags: variables, batch-file, text

I am trying to make a batch file use a string from a text file as a variable.
So for instance I have a text file with:

```
Test
```

and I want it to return:

```
Your name is Test
```

using an echo command.Is it possible?

Comment: you can know its possible or not by running it yourself. If that's your only question.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to say. Could you rephrase?

Comment: In your example `Test` would *not* be a variable but a simple value. So what you really want is to read a list of strings and concatenate them to a fixed string, right?

Comment: Yes thats exactly what Im trying to do. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. Just did:

```
(
set /p var=
)<File.txt
```

Then when I echo `%var%` I end up with the string in the text file.